# Custom axis don't zooms fine in TeeChart .Net

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

i have multiple series on one chart. Each of them is asociated with vertical custom axis(so i don't use any basic axis), automatic propreties turned off. When i'm zooming series, everything works well, execpt my custom axes(vertical), the scale of axes doesn't change, at the same time horizantal(basic) axis scales changes fine. what should i do to fix it, or it can be made only manualy every time when i want to zoom/unzoom?
   And, one more question, is it possible to make one universal grid for all custom axes? Basicaly every axis has it own grid, and it looks terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Custom axis don't support zoom. You should do something similar to the example I posted [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9563&p=39333&hilit=custom%20axis%20zoom#p39333).